# Returning the last posted data

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, currently my query looks something like this:

```
$d = $this->db->select()
              ->order_by('assessment_id', 'asc')
              ->order_by('date_completed', 'desc')
              ->group_by('assessment_id desc')
              ->where('category_id', $x)
              ->get('users_assessments')
              ->result();
```

I'm trying to get the last posted data in the category $x, but I cann't figure out a way to return the last posted data. It returns just the data of the 1st post ever made in the category $x.

How can I make this, so it would return me the data of the last post in category $x?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult answer this without knowing wich of the fields you mean with "last posted data", or your table structure.
Anyway, you've an error in your query, you don't use "desc" in group by, what did you want to do?

```
$sql = $this->db->select()
            ->from('users_assessments')
            ->where('category_id',$x)
            ->order_by('date_completed','desc')
            //->group_by('assessment_id')
            ->limit(1)
            ->get();
$result = $sql->row();
```

This might work, but I'm just guessing...Why do you order by 'assessment_id' ? What does that contain? Also, I figured that "date_completed" is what you mean by "last posted data", otherwise you might want to add some details in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Is category primary key than use select_max of category and put it in where.

Comment: No, category is not primary key.

Comment: @A Bag than you have to save it in database.

Comment: No, there can be multiple entries in one category. That's why it's not primary, neither is it unique.

Comment: You can save it in a variable like config and than when ever new value you have you can replace it.

Comment: I don't see how this could help me?